# NullPointerException adding substring from string to array list

Tags: java, arrays, string, exception, arraylist

What I'm trying to do is add a substring from a `String` to an `ArrayList`. basically adding every letter in the string to an index in the `ArrayList`. After that i have a print statement just to see if the letters were added to the `ArrayList` (thats the second for loop under `makearraylisOfChosenWord`). However, when i run this with or without the print statement, it gives me a `NullPointerException`. Is it because I'm adding the letters to the arraylist in a wrong way in the first for loop?
thanks for the help
heres the code:

```
String[] wordList = {"apple", "orange", "strawberry", "banana"};
String chosenWord;

//Make an array list to hold one letter of the chosen word at each index
void makeArrayListOfChosenWord(){
    ArrayList<String> lettersOfChosenWord = new ArrayList<String> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < chosenWord.length(); i++) {
        lettersOfChosenWord.add(chosenWord.substring(i, i+1));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lettersOfChosenWord.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((lettersOfChosenWord.get(i)).toString());
    }

}

//Let the game pick a random word from the word list
void setRandomWord(){
    int wordListLength = wordList.length;
    int pickRandomWord = (int) (Math.random() * wordListLength);
    String createRandomWord = wordList[pickRandomWord];
    chosenWord = createRandomWord;
    System.out.printf("the word is %s letters long", chosenWord.length());
}
```

Comment: The two methods are entirely separate - how are they related? It would really help if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: actually the setrandomword picks a random word from the word list, and if you look, the instance variable chosenword is given the random word picked, (its in the setrandomword method, line 4) and the makearraylist method uses the chosenword variable

Comment: Ah, with you. And is the second method *definitely* called before the first method? This is the sort of thing which a short but complete program would make clear. It would also help if you'd show the stack trace so we know where the exception is happening.

Comment: There is no problem, you need to call setRandomWord, then makeArrayListOfChosenWord, and no exception should be thrown

Comment: ok, working on it, thanks for the tips

Comment: It's strange, 'cause it seems to be working for all words you've listed. Like @JonSkeet said, try to check the order of methods calls.

Comment: Ahhhh Frederic Close, I think I forgot to call the setRandomWord method... let me try that really quick.

Comment: Yes, my comment got them the wrong way round - you *do* need to call `setRandomWord`, or `chosenWord` will be null... which is why you'll get a NullPointerException. Please take this as a lesson in why it's really *really* useful to post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. We'd have come up with the answer in about a minute (if that) if you'd included a complete program.

Comment: ok it worked, thank you frederic for bringing that to my attention, i completely forgot to call the setRandomWord method

Comment: and thank you jon, i will take your advice on the posting a short program

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you call your `setRandomWord` method before you call `makeArrayListOfChosenWord` method no NullPointerException will be thrown. No if-check is needed in your code for this condition.

Answer (score 0):

I was just thinking about your problem and would try to use an `ArrayList` of `Character` instead of `String`. This is imo ok, because you mentioned that you are splitting up a `String` into single `Character`s, so `ArrayList<Character>()` seems a reasonable approach.

For splitting up the `String` I would make use of the method [`toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29):

```
String str = "abcd...";
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
  chars.add(c);
}
```

Comment: that sounds interesting, i've never seen that method before, thank you for mentioning it, i will try to implement that (after i understand it of course, lol)

Comment: however, does toCharArray() make it into a regular array or an array list? because I'd like to be able to delete certain letters from the arraylist when the program initiates

Comment: toCharArray returns you an array. The for-loop adds each of the array elements to your ArrayList. Using this way avoids the substring-method and possible ArrayOutOfBoundExceptions

Comment: Ok I see, I will try to do that then,